# Fishing simulator

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I'm new to Python, for a school project I created a "fishing simulator". Basically, it is a use of random. I know that my code is repetitive towards the end, but I don't know how to simplify it.

```
import time
import random
fishing = True
a = b = c = d = e = 0 #define multiple variables as same thing
print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print ("Welcome to Lake Tocowaga")
print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
time.sleep(1)
name = input("What is your name fisherman?")
answer = input("Would you like to go fishing, " + name + "?")
if answer.lower() == "no":
    fishing == False
while fishing == True:    
    time.sleep(1)
    answer = input("Throw out your line, or go home?")
    if answer == "go home":
        fishing = False
        er = float(e / (a + b + c + d))
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("Thanks for playing " + name + "!")
        print("You caught:", str(a), "cod, ", str(b), "salmon, ", str(c), "shark, ", str(d), "wildfish. \nEfficiency Rate: ", str(er), ".")
    else:
        t = random.randrange(1, 7)
        if t == 1:
            a += 1
            print("You caught a cod!")
        elif t == 2:
            b += 1
            print("You caught a salmon!")
        elif t == 3:
            c += 1
            print("You caught a shark!")
        elif t == 4:
            d += 1
            print("You caught a wildfish!")
        elif t >= 5:
            e += 1
            print("You caught nothing!")
```

Comment: Why did you tag this question as [tag:python-2.x]? I'm not convinced that it would work correctly in Python 2.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Welcome to CodeReview. It's never too early to develop good coding habits, and reviewing your code is about the best way to do so.

First, congratulations on writing a clean, straightforward program. While you do have some issues (below), they're not major, and your program seems appropriate for its level.

Now, for the issues ;-)

## Use whitespace

Python requires you to use horizontal whitespace. But you should also use vertical whitespace (aka "blank lines") to organize the different parts of your code into *paragraphs.*

This huge block:

```
import time
import random
fishing = True
a = b = c = d = e = 0 #define multiple variables as same thing
print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print ("Welcome to Lake Tocowaga")
print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
time.sleep(1)
name = input("What is your name fisherman?")
answer = input("Would you like to go fishing, " + name + "?")
if answer.lower() == "no":
    fishing == False
while fishing == True:
```

would read better if it were broken up like so:

```
import time
import random

fishing = True
a = b = c = d = e = 0 #define multiple variables as same thing

print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
print ("Welcome to Lake Tocowaga")
print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
time.sleep(1)

name = input("What is your name fisherman?")
answer = input("Would you like to go fishing, " + name + "?")

if answer.lower() == "no":
    fishing == False

while fishing == True:
```

All I did was add a few blank lines, but I was trying to show that "these things go together" and "these things are in sequence but not related".

## Use meaningful names:

Which one of these is the shark?

```
a = b = c = d = e = 0
```

I have no idea. But if you named them appropriately:

```
cod = shark = wildfish = salmon = nothing = 0
```

I would know for sure!

## Use named constants

This line appears three times:

```
print ("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

It's probably hard to get the right number of tilde characters, unless you are copy/pasting it. And if you're doing that, it's probably a pain. Instead, create a name for the tildes. By convention, constants are spelled in uppercase. (It's not really a constant, but since constants are spelled in upper case, if you name it in upper case you'll know not to modify it.)

```
H_LINE = "~" * 32

print(H_LINE)
print("Welcome to Lake Tocowaga")
print(H_LINE)
```

## Put last things last

There's a place for everything. And everything should be in its place. The place for printing a summary would be at the bottom.

You had a good idea with your `while fishing:` loop. But instead of immediately printing the summary when you respond to the user input, just change the variable and let the loop fail, then print the summary at the bottom. It's more "natural" (and it makes your loops easier to read!).

```
while fishing == True:    
    time.sleep(1)
    answer = input("Throw out your line, or go home?")
    if answer == "go home":
        fishing = False
        er = float(e / (a + b + c + d))
        print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
        print("Thanks for playing " + name + "!")
        print("You caught:", str(a), "cod, ", str(b), "salmon, ", str(c), "shark, ", str(d), "wildfish. \nEfficiency Rate: ", str(er), ".")
    else:
        ...
```

Becomes:

```
while fishing == True:    
    time.sleep(1)
    answer = input("Throw out your line, or go home?")
    if answer == "go home":
        fishing = False
    else:
        ...

er = float(e / (a + b + c + d))
print(H_LINE)
print("Thanks for playing " + name + "!")
print("You caught:", str(a), "cod, ", str(b), "salmon, ", str(c), "shark, ", str(d), "wildfish. \nEfficiency Rate: ", str(er), ".")
```

## Let the built-in functions do their job

You are calling functions that you don't need to call. The result of "true" division between integers is a float. You don't need to call `float(e / (a + b + c + d))`. And if you *did* need to call it, you'd be calling it too late!

Likewise, `print` knows how to handle integers and floating point numbers. You don't need to `print(..., str(a), ...)` when you can just do:  `print(..., a, ...)`.

Answer (score 25):

A few simple things.

---

```
a = b = c = d = e = 0
```

This is bad for a couple reasons:

- Those are all nondescript, overly simple names. There's no way to tell what they represent just by looking at them.
- You're shoving their declarations/definitions all on one line. This is generally regarded as poor practice. Say I'm looking for where `c` is defined. It's much easier to find it when I can be sure that I'm looking for exactly `c = ...` somewhere. It's harder to find though when it's declared half way through a line.

In both cases, you're sacrificing readability for brevity. Avoid doing this unless you're code golfing. Readability takes precedence over nearly everything else.

---

`fishing = True` is the third line in your file, yet you don't use it until later. Unless it's a constant, it's a good idea to declare variables near where they're first used. When someone's reading your code and wants to see the definition of `fishing`, it's more efficient if they only have to look up a line or two instead of needing to scroll to the top of the file.

---

`while fishing == True:` can simply be written as `while fishing:`.

---

You actually have a bug. `fishing == False` should be `fishing = False`.

---

`if answer.lower() == "no":` could be written to be more "tolerant" (but less exact) by only checking the first letter:

```
if answer.lower().startswith("n"):
```

Now input like "nope" will work as well. Whether or not you want this behavior is another story though. If you had other answers that require "n" as the first letter, obviously this would break things.

Comment: About `while fishing`: Suppose, say by user input or something, `fishing` is a string, then `while fishing` would always be `True`. Isn't it safer to write `while fishing is True`?

Comment: `if answer.lower()[0] == "n":` will break if `answer` is an empty string. Better `if answer.lower().startswith('n'):`. :-)

Comment: @niko `fishing` is never assigned user input. If it was accidentally, any behavior resulting from that would be incorrect, so I don't think using `is True` would help anything.

Comment: @TrebledJ Yes, good call.

Comment: @niko no, don't do this. Defensive coding is a good paradigm, but it has to do with handling unknown inputs, not elements of your own code. `while fishing` is the correct statement here.

Answer (score 24):

First off I think your use case is a nifty way of getting into Python, and it looks like aside from the bugs that others have already pointed out you'll likely soon be unstoppable.

However, instead of *simplifying* the code I'd suggest modularizing as well as making use of `__doc__` strings. It'll make adding features much easier in the future, and if you so choose, allow for making a full application with [*`Kivy`*](https://kivy.org/), [*`Blender`*](https://www.blender.org/), or one of the other many GUI frameworks for Python development. Plus modularizing or abstraction allows for simplifying the intentions/usage.

> Some notes before diving-in...
>
> - it's probably a good idea to get a snack and drink; I'm a *bit verbose* and am about to compress *some years* of knowledge
> - *`__bar__`* when spoken is [*"dunder bar"*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dunder) , and the *phylum* that they're classified under are [*"magic methods"*](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/)
> - what I share is **not** *gospel* as such, but a collection of tricks I wish someone had shown me when I was getting into Python
>
> ... okay back on track.

Here's some example code inspired by yours that shows some of what I was going on about in your question's comments...

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import random


print_separator = "".join(['_' for _ in range(9)])
__author__ = "S0AndS0"

#
# Functions
#

def question(message):
    """ Returns response to `message` from user """
    return input("{message}? ".format(message = message))


#
# Classes
#

class Gone_Fishing(dict):
    """
    Gone_Fishing is a simple simulation inspired by
    [Python - Fishing Simulator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/217357/197446)

    ## Arguments

    - `fishes`, `dict`ionary such as `{'cod': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [1, 2]}}`
    - `min_chance`, `int`eger of min number that `random.randint` may generate
    - `max_chance`, `int`eger of max number that `random.randint` may generate
    """

    def __init__(self, fishes, min_chance = 1, max_chance = 10, **kwargs):
        super(Gone_Fishing, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update(fishes = fishes,
                    chances = {'min': min_chance, 'max': max_chance})

    @staticmethod
    def keep_fishing(message, expected):
        """ Return `bool`ean of if `response` to `message` matches `expected` """
        response = question(message)
        if not response or not isinstance(response, str):
            return False

        return response.lower() == expected

    @property
    def dump_cooler(self):
        """
        Returns `score`, a `dict`ionary similar to `{'cod': 5, 'tire': 2}`,
        after printing and reseting _`amount`s_ caught
        """
        score = {}
        for fish, data in self['fishes'].items():
            if data['amount'] > 0:
                score.update({fish: data['amount']})
                if data['amount'] > 1 and data.get('plural'):
                    fish = data['plural']

                print("{amount} {fish}".format(**{
                    'fish': fish,
                    'amount': data['amount']}))

                data['amount'] = 0

        return score

    def catch(self, chance):
        """ Returns `None` or name of `fish` caught based on `chance` """
        caught = []
        for fish, data in self['fishes'].items():
            if chance in data['chances']:
                caught.append(fish)

        return caught

    def main_loop(self):
        """
        Asks questions, adds to _cooler_ anything caught, and prints score when finished
        """
        first = True
        message = 'Go fishing'
        expected = 'yes'
        while self.keep_fishing(message, expected):
            time.sleep(1)
            if first:
                first = False
                message = "Keep fishing"

            chances = random.randint(self['chances']['min'], self['chances']['max'])
            caught = self.catch(chances)
            if caught:
                for fish in caught:
                    self['fishes'][fish]['amount'] += 1
                    fancy_fish = ' '.join(fish.split('_')).title()
                    print("You caught a {fish}".format(fish = fancy_fish))
            else:
                print("Nothing was caught this time.")

        print("{0}\nThanks for playing".format(print_separator))
        if True in [x['amount'] > 0 for x in self['fishes'].values()]:
            print("You caught")
            self.dump_cooler
        print(print_separator)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """
    This block of code is not executed during import
    and instead is usually run when a file is executed,
    eg. `python gone_fishing.py`, making it a good
    place for simple unit tests and example usage.
    """
    gone_fishing = Gone_Fishing(
        fishes = {
            'cod': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [1]},
            'salmon': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [5]},
            'shark': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [9, 10], 'plural': 'sharks'},
            'wild_fish': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [7], 'plural': 'wild_fishes'},
            'old_shoe': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [10, 15], 'plural': 'old_shoes'},
            'tire': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [2, 19], 'plural': 'tires'},
        },
        min_chances = 0,
        max_chances = 20,
    )

    gone_fishing.main_loop()
```

... okay there's a *bit* going on up there, so feel free to dissect it's operation by adding [*`breakpoints`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980836/2632107) or *`print(something)`* lines.

---

Here's what output of running the above script may look like

```
# python gone_fishing.py
Go fishing? 'yes'
You caught a Wild Fish
Keep fishing? 'yes'
Nothing was caught this time.
Keep fishing? 'yes'
You caught a Shark
You caught a Old Shoe
Keep fishing? 'yes'
Nothing was caught this time.
# ... trimmed for brevity
Keep fishing? 'no'
_________
Thanks for playing
You caught
2 sharks
1 tire
2 wild_fishes
1 cod
_________
```

---

Taking it from the top `print_separator = "".join(['_' for _ in range(9)])` is what I like to use when generating strings of repeating characters because it's easy to make something that outputs `_-_-_` via `"-".join(['_' for _ in range(3)])`.

> Note from the future; check the comments of this answer for some swell suggestions from @Izaak van Dongen.

---

By defining a class that inherits from the built in `dict`ionary `class` (that's what the `class Gone_Fishing(dict):` line did), I'm being a bit lazy as this allows for *dumping* all saved states via...

```py
print(gone_fishing)
# -> {'cod': {'amount': 2, 'chances': [1]}, ...}
```

> ... and while I'm on the tangent of getting info back out...

```py
print(gone_fishing.main_loop.__doc__)
# Or
# help(gone_fishing.main_loop)
```

> ... will print the previously mentioned `__doc__` strings.

... and figuring out where you too can avoid re-inventing the wheel is just something that'll get picked up over time. Personally I choose to view it as *expanding one's vocabulary*, when I discover some built-in that's been waiting to solve some edge-case.

---

The `__init__` `method` *absorbs* three arguments and re-assigns'em with `self.update()` so that other methods that use the `self` argument are able to get and/or modify `class` saved states; more on that latter.

> Side note; the `__init__` method is one of many that are called implicitly by preforming some action with an object, eg. `__add__` is called implicitly by using `+` between two `Objects` with a `__add__` method (side-side note, I'll get into why that was an *`a`* and not an *`an`* in a bit), which is why the following works with lists...

```py
list_one = [3, 2, 1]
list_two = [0, -1, -2]

list_one + list_two
# -> [3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2]
```

That bit with `**kwargs` stands for *`key word arguments`* which passes things as a *bare* `dict`ionary, the other syntax you may run across is `*args`, which passes things as a *bare* `list` of arguments; there be some *fanciness* that can be done with this syntax that I'll not get into at this point other than saying that context matters. However, you'll find some examples of passing an unwrapped dictionary, such as to `format` via `print("{amount} {fish}".format(**{...}))`, which hint hint, is a great way of passing variable parameter names.

> This is one of those idiomatic things that you can pick-up with some experimentation (and grokking-out others' code bases); it's super powerful so use it often but be kind to your future self too.

The bit with `super(Gone_Fishing, self).__init__(**kwargs)` is what allows the `Gone_Fishing` `class` to call `dict`'s `__init__` from within it's own `__init__` `method`... indeed that was a little convoluted so taking a sec to unpack that...

```py
class SomeThing(dict):
    def __init__(self, an_argument = None, **kwargs):
        super(SomeThing, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update({'an_argument': an_argument})
```

... it's possible to call `self.update()` from within `SomeThing.___init__` without causing confusion of intent, where as to have `SomeThing` still operate as a `dict`ionary, eg. assigning `something = SomeThing(spam = 'Spam')` without causing errors, one should use `super(SomeThing, self).__init__(**kwargs)` to allow Python to preform it's voodoo with figuring out which inheriting `class`'ll take responsibility for those arguments.

> That does mean that one could do `class SomeThing(dict, Iterator)`, and have that mean something but I'll not get into that here; kinda already covered that specifically on [*math stack*](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/657433/s0ands0) in regards to graph modeling and prioritization.

---

The `@staticmethod` and other [*`decorators`*](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-in-python/) are ways of denoting a special use `method`. In the case of `property`s they operate *similarly* to `Object` properties, eg...

```py
class Test_Obj:
    pass

o = Test_Obj()
o.foo = 'Foo'

print(o.foo)
# -> Foo
```

... but can only be *gotten* not *set*, which makes'em a great place to stash dynamic or semiprivate properties about an `Object`.

In the case of `staticmethod`s, they're not passed a reference to `self` so cannot easily access or modify saved states, but they can be more easily used without initializing so operate similarly to regular functions, eg...

```py
responses = []

responses.append(question("Where to"))
print("I heard -> {response}".format(response = responses[-1]))
for _ in range(7):
    responses.append(question("... are you sure"))
    print("I heard -> {response}".format(response = responses[-1]))

print("Okay... though...")
```

> Note also the various `.format()` usages are to show ways of *future prepping* (for perhaps using `f strings` in the future), as well as making strings somewhat more explicit.

Generally I use'em to make the intended usage more explicit but that's not to say that you couldn't get lost in the amount of options available just for decorating a `method`.

> Note from the future; as pointed out by @Maarten Fabré I indeed slipped in some superfluous use of the `staticmethod` decorator, good catch there, and this'll now serve as an example of *getting carried away* when `decorat`ing.
>
> Generally I use `staticmethod`s when I've a class that isn't concerned with it's internal state but isn't large enough to warrant it's own file, very edge case kinda thing, and usually it means that I should probably split'em out into a file that organizes similar functions. Hopefully recent edits now look closer to *proper* for future readers.

---

That bit within the `main_loop` `method` with `while self.keep_fishing(message, expected)`, when unwrapped I think you'll really like, it's returning `True` or `False` at the *top* of every iteration based on asking the user a question and comparing their response with what's expected.

And the bit with `if True in [x['amount'] > 0 for x in self['fishes'].values()]` is something that *masks* data using [*`list comprehensions`*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), I'll advise against getting too *fancy* with'em, and instead try to utilize'em whenever it doesn't make code less readable. Also don't get to attached to such cleverness because [*`numpy`*](http://www.numpy.org/), [*`pandas`*](https://pandas.pydata.org/), or one of the many other libraries, will preform similar tasks far faster.

---

The things happening bellow the `if __name__ == '__main__':`, aside from the *doc string* ...

> Side note for those new to Python; sure you could call'em *"dunder docs"* and those *in the know* would know what you where saying, but they'd also likely *smize* at ya too, and saying *"dundar doc string"* if timed when a listener is drinking could have messy consequences... so "pro-tip", callem *"doc strings"* to be *`super` `class`y* when talking about Python code ;-)

```py
gone_fishing = Gone_Fishing(fishes = {
    'cod': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [1]},
    'salmon': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [2]},
    'shark': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [3], 'plural': 'sharks'},
    'wild_fish': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [4], 'plural': 'wild_fishes'},
    'old_shoe': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [5, 6], 'plural': 'old_shoes'},
    'tire': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [7, 8], 'plural': 'tires'},
})
```

... and how the above is parsed could take *some words* to do a full *stack trace*, but the gist is that `chances` is a `list` that you could even have overlapping integers, eg. a `shark` who had an `old_shoe` inside could be...

```py
gone_fishing['fishes']['shark']['chances'].append(5)
```

... though without adjustments to other values that would make for a very large shoal of soul hungry sharks.

> Note from the future; I've made adjustments to the code to enable overlapping values and returning of more than one result; there probably be *better* ways of doing it but this is also an example of iterative development now.

---

When you've figured out how `plural` is an optional key value pair within a nested dictionary you'll start seeing similar things in other code (at least it's one of those things I've not been unable to unsee), try not to get messy with that trick though, otherwise I think it's self-explanatory as to the intentions of it's usage.

---

The arguments that I didn't assign, `min_chance` and `max_chance`, much like the `chances` with `sharks` could be updated similarly, eg...

```py
gone_fishing['chances']['max'] = 20
```

... though initializing a new trip would look like...

```py
another_fishing_trip = Gone_Fishing(
    fishes = {
        'cod': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [1]},
        'salmon': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [5]},
        'shark': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [9, 10], 'plural': 'sharks'},
        'wild_fish': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [7], 'plural': 'wild_fishes'},
        'old_shoe': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [10, 15], 'plural': 'old_shoes'},
        'tire': {'amount': 0, 'chances': [2, 19], 'plural': 'tires'},
    },
    min_chances = 0,
    max_chances = 20,
)
```

... which serves as an example of something you'd be wise to avoid doing to your own code, swapping words especially isn't going to win any points from a *future self* or other developers.

---

There's certainly more room for improvement, eg. having *`gone_fishing['fishes'][fish_name]['amount']`* subtracted from, while adding to *`gone_fishing['cooler']`* or similar structure; just for a start. But this was all just to expose quick-n-dirty methods of organizing the problem space with Object Oriented Programing.

Hopefully having code with a bit more abstraction shows ya that going with something that looks a bit more complex can allow for simplifying the usage and future [*`feature creep`*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep). Please keep us posted if ya make something more out of your learning project.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I think you did a grat job on your first answer here. Keep it going!

Comment: Thank you! I'm self taught so am glad that this seems to be helping others getting into Python development.

Comment: A lot of great advice, but I would like to note that this: 
    `print_separator = "".join(['_' for _ in range(9)])`
Can be shortened to this: 
    `print_separator = '_' * 9`

Comment: Quite right @shellster, `print_seperator = '_' * 9` is certainly more readable and quicker to write. I mainly use `print_separator = "".join(['_' for _ in range(9)])` because it allows for future fanciness like `_--_--_` via `"--".join(['_' for _ in range(3)])`, which I think is worth a few more characters in setup. That said I don't think `print_seperator = lambda sep_main, sep_sub, ammount: "{sep_sub}".format(sep_sub = sep_sub).join([sep_main for _ in range(ammount)])` would be worth using except in jest.

Comment: `print("{amount} {fish}".format(**{'fish': fish, 'amount': data['amount']}))` -- why not `print("{amount} {fish}".format(fish=fish, amount=data['amount']))`?

Comment: Both are perfectly valid @kevinsa5; for one I sometimes get board with picking one, second the code is a compressed form of lots of various ways of doing things. Combined with code read time far exceeds execution time, I wanted to make sure that there where _plenty-o-goodies_ to find on repeat reads. And more specific to your question `print("{amount} {fish}".format(**{'amount': amount, 'fish': fist}))` is more _explicit_ in regards to what's going on _under the hood_; well if I remember correctly.

Comment: @S0AndS0 This is obviously a tiny nitpick, but even then it would probably be better to use one of `"--".join('_' * 3)` (limitations: underscore must be single character and builds intermediary string), `"--".join('_' for _ in range(3))`, `"--".join(itertools.repeat('_', 3))`, depending whether or not you like `itertools`. Constructing an intermediary list in memory here is really not necessary.

Comment: Indeed an intermediate `list` is _uncalled for_ in the example use case, and I'm glad that you've pointed out a plethora of other options. That first one is sweet @Izaak van Dongen! And has some interesting outputs when more than one character is used, eg. `"--".join('_|' * 3)` `->` `_--|--_--|--_--|`. Especially when compared to the output of your other suggestion `"--".join('_|' for _ in range(3))` `->` `_|--_|--_|`... definitely something that I'll keep in mind for fancy dividers.

Comment: If you really want to use classes (do you?), I would expect a class for a Fish, a Pond, a Fisher and perhaps a Game. Not like this. All these staticmethods are unneeded on the class, but should go in the module namespace. You make a lot of simple things extra complicated. I suggest you post this piece of code as a seperate question, then you can get some tips on how to improve this.

Comment: @Maarten Fabré I was really tempted! Like you'd maybe believe. Selection of fishing poles, different bait shops, `import`ing, all sorts of good stuff... And you're absolutely correct that there's little reason for `staticmethod`s within a `class`; was kinda getting worried that no one had called me out on this earlier. It's something to play around with to better expose avenues of improvement; I'll critique my code far harsher than someone else's. Given a little more time I may `git push` something a bit more thought-out and post a question with cross-linking back to here.

Comment: This is massively overzealous use of OO. Your descriptions are great, your code is _fine_ -- probably even better than fine -- but this isn't a great use case for object-oriented behavior.

Answer (score 11):

This is another inprovement using a dictionary. Currently all of your data is hardcoded and distributed somewhere in the code. If you wanted to add another fish, you would have to add a variable `f`, extend `random.randint` (so the chance for nothing does not decrease) and finally add it to the `if` conditions and the printing.

That is a lot of work just to add one more fish. Instead I would propose to use a dictionary of possible fishing outcomes and their chance of being caught. You can then use this with [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), which takes a `weights` argument detailing the probabilities.

```
pond = {'cod': 1, 'salmon': 1, 'shark': 1, 'wildfish': 1, 'nothing': 2}
```

The probabilities are here just relative to each other, `random.choices` normalizes them for you. All fish have the same probability and getting nothing has double the probability of any single fish.

Your loop also does not need the `fishing` variable at all, just `break` it when the user is done fishing.

Whenever you need to count something, using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is probably a good idea. It basically works like a dictionary and has the nice feature that it assumes all elements have a count of zero.

In Python 3.6 a new way to format strings was introduced, the [`f-string`](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

```
from collections import Counter
from random import choices
from time import sleep

POND = {'cod': 1, 'salmon': 1, 'shark': 1, 'wildfish': 1, 'nothing': 2}

name = input("What is your name fisherman? ")

caught = Counter()
while True:
    keep_fishing = input("Throw out your line, or go home? ")
    if keep_fishing == "go home":
        break
    sleep(1)
    result = choices(list(POND), weights=POND.values(), k=1)[0]
    print(f"You caught: {result}")
    caught[result] += 1

print(f"\nThanks for playing, {name}!")
print("You caught:")
for fish, n in caught.most_common():
    if fish != "nothing":
        print(n, fish)
```

Comment: For the behavior to be the same as the original code, nothing should have chance 3

Comment: @Vaelus `randrange` is exclusive of the end, so produces vales from 1 to 6 (inclusive), therefore only 5 and 6 produce `nothing`.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. Yet another reason to use your method.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers, you can also take advantage of python dictionaries:

```
a = b = c = d = e = 0
...
else:
    t = random.randrange(1, 7)
    if t == 1:
        a += 1
        print("You caught a cod!")
    elif t == 2:
        b += 1
        print("You caught a salmon!")
    elif t == 3:
        c += 1
        print("You caught a shark!")
    elif t == 4:
        d += 1
        print("You caught a wildfish!")
    elif t >= 5:
        e += 1
        print("You caught nothing!")
```

Becomes:

```
caught_fish = {
    'cod': 0,
    'salmon': 0,
    'shark': 0,
    'wildfish': 0,
    'nothing': 0,
}
...
else:
    t = random.randrange(1,7)
    # clamp 't' to dictionary size
    if t > len(caught_fish):
        t = len(caught_fish)
    # pick a type of fish from the list of keys of 'caught_fish' using index 't'
    type_of_fish = list(caught_fish)[t - 1]
    # update the dictionary
    caught_fish[type_of_fish] += 1
    # print what type of fish was caught, or if no fish was caught
    article = 'a ' if type_of_fish != 'nothing' else ''
    print("You caught {}{}!".format(article, type_of_fish))
```